# Windows Task Scheduler - Task ending

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, tasks, scheduling

I'm trying to schedule a task in windows task scheduler, that will run on every user logon, as the user creating it. The task needs to run an .exe, and then stop. The thing is, it keeps running for as long as the .exe runs. So user logs on, the task fires up, the .exe starts running, but the task itself never stop and it's status remains "running" Btw, the .exe needs to run all the time.

If for example i set the task at a specific time, it runs at that specific time, runs the .exe, and the task ends, going back to a ready status which is what i need, in a way.

Is there a way to make a task start on a user logon, start an exe, and then stop that same task, until it's triggered again (on another logon). If i stop the task manually, it also stops the running .exe, which it shouldn't.

Comment: What is your task action? running desured .EXE? running some script? etc.? And why to stop the task is so critical?

Comment: It needs to run an .EXE. I guess i could say it's not "critical", but i don't understand why would it run simultaneously with the .EXE - if one of them is stopped, they are both stopped. Plus if you consider that the .EXE needs to run 24/7, the task will too which is something i don't really like.

Comment: The "task running" is the same as "executing task's action". Action is "running exe"? "exe is running" == "task is running". Create simple script (vbs or ever batch) which starts your exe and exits.

Comment: That's an option yes, but the question is: Why if i schedule a task at some time (xx:xx) to run an .EXE it starts at xx:xx, runs the exe and the task finishes and goes to state ready, but when i do it on logon it keeps running as long as the exe is running...?(all the time, and if i stop it manually it stops the exe too)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What problem is being caused by the task running as long as the .EXE is executing?

Comment: There isn't really a problem, but knowing that the .exe needs to run all day, everyday, i was not sure if a task running for 24/7 is a good idea resource-wise. Also as i already mentioned, i couldn't understand why it would never stop running after the .EXE is started, like when there's a run time specified.